# unexpected token < JSON at position 0

Tags: php

so i make this code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_name">Username</label>
                <input type="text"  id="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mac_address">Mac Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="mac_address" id="mac_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mac Address">
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="load('<?php echo $base_path?>user.php?action=index')">Back</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="user_store()">Save</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>
    </div>
```

but when i submit my data to database it shown error like this "unexpected token < JSON at position 0" can u guys help me with this error?

My full code

```
<?php session_start(); 

        include 'include/global.php';
        include 'include/function.php';

    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'index') {
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('title').html('User');

            function user_delete(user_id, user_name) {

                var r = confirm("Delete user "+user_name+" ?");

                if (r == true) {

                    push('user.php?action=delete&user_id='+user_id);

                }
            }

            function user_register(user_id, user_name) {

                $('body').ajaxMask();

                regStats = 0;
                regCt = -1;
                try
                {
                    timer_register.stop();
                }
                catch(err)  
                {
                    console.log('Registration timer has been init');
                }


                var limit = 4;
                var ct = 1;
                var timeout = 5000;

                timer_register = $.timer(timeout, function() {                  
                    console.log("'"+user_name+"' registration checking...");
                    user_checkregister(user_id,$("#user_finger_"+user_id).html());
                    if (ct>=limit || regStats==1) 
                    {
                        timer_register.stop();
                        console.log("'"+user_name+"' registration checking end");
                        if (ct>=limit && regStats==0)
                        {
                            alert("'"+user_name+"' registration fail!");
                            $('body').ajaxMask({ stop: true });
                        }                       
                        if (regStats==1)
                        {
                            $("#user_finger_"+user_id).html(regCt);
                            alert("'"+user_name+"' registration success!");
                            $('body').ajaxMask({ stop: true });
                            load('user.php?action=index');
                        }
                    }
                    ct++;
                });
            }

            function user_checkregister(user_id, current) {
                $.ajax({
                    url         :   "user.php?action=checkreg&user_id="+user_id+"&current="+current,
                    type        :   "GET",
                    success     :   function(data)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   
                                            if (res.result)
                                            {
                                                regStats = 1;
                                                $.each(res, function(key, value){
                                                    if (key=='current')
                                                    {                                                       
                                                        regCt = value;
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch(err)
                                        {
                                            alert(err.message);
                                        }
                                    }
                });
            }

        </script>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="load('<?php echo $base_path?>user.php?action=create')">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>

<?php

        $user = getUser();

        if (count($user) > 0) {

            echo    "<div class='row'>"
                    ."<div class='col-md-12'>"
                        ."<table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>"
                                ."<thead>"
                                    ."<tr>"
                                        ."<th class='col-md-4'>User ID</th>"
                                        ."<th class='col-md-4'>Username</th>"
                                        ."<th class='col-md-2'>Template</th>"
                                        ."<th class='col-md-2'>Action</th>"
                                    ."</tr>"
                                ."</thead>"
                                ."<tbody>";

            foreach ($user as $row) {

                $finger             = getUserFinger($row['user_id']);
                $register           = '';
                $verification       = '';
                $url_register       = base64_encode($base_path."register.php?user_id=".$row['user_id']);
                $url_verification   = base64_encode($base_path."verification.php?user_id=".$row['user_id']);

                if (count($finger) == 0) {

                    $register = "<a href='finspot:FingerspotReg;$url_register' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' onclick=\"user_register('".$row['user_id']."','".$row['user_name']."')\">Register</a>";

                } else {

                    $verification = "<a href='finspot:FingerspotVer;$url_verification' class='btn btn-xs btn-success'>Login</a>";

                }

                echo                    "<tr>"
                                    ."<td>".$row['user_id']."</td>"
                                    ."<td>".$row['user_name']."</td>"
                                    ."<td><code id='user_finger_".$row['user_id']."'>".count($finger)."</code></td>"
                                    ."<td>"
                                        ."<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' onclick=\"user_delete('".$row['user_id']."','".$row['user_name']."')\">Delete</button>"
                                        ."&nbsp"
                                        ."$register"
                                        ."$verification"
                                    ."</td>"
                                    ."</tr>";

            }

            echo
                                "</tbody>"
                        ."</table>"
                    ."</div>"
                ."</div>";

        } else {

            echo 'User Empty';

        }

    } elseif (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'create') {
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('title').html('Add user');

            function user_store() {

                user_name   = $('#user_name').val();

                push('user.php?action=store&user_name='+user_name);

            }

        </script>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user_name">Username</label>
                    <input type="text"  id="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mac_address">Mac Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="mac_address" id="mac_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mac Address">
                </div>
                <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="load('<?php echo $base_path?>user.php?action=index')">Back</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="user_store()">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
        </div>

<?php
    } elseif (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'store') {

        $res        = array();
                $res['result']  = false;

        if ($_GET['user_name'] == '' || !isset($_GET['user_name']) || empty($_GET['user_name'])) {

            $res['user_name'] = "username can't empty";

        } elseif (isset($_GET['user_name']) && !empty($_GET['user_name'])) {

            $user_name = checkUserName($_GET['user_name']);

            if ($user_name != 1) {

                $res['user_name'] = $user_name;

            }

        }

        if (count($res) > 1) {

            echo json_encode($res);

        } else {

            $sql    = "INSERT INTO demo_user SET user_name='".$_GET['user_name']."' ";
            $sql1   = "INSERT INTO demo_macaddress SET macaddress='".$_POST['mac_address']."' ";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $result = mysql_query($sql1);

            if ($result) {

                $res['result']  = true;
                $res['reload']  = "user.php?action=index";

            } else {

                $res['server'] = "Error insert data!";

            }

            echo json_encode($res);

        }

    } elseif (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {

        $sql1       = "DELETE FROM demo_user WHERE user_id = '".$_GET['user_id']."' ";
        $result1    = mysql_query($sql1);

        $sql2       = "DELETE FROM demo_finger WHERE user_id = '".$_GET['user_id']."' ";
        $result2    = mysql_query($sql2);

        if ($result1 && $result2) {

            $res['result']  = true;
            $res['reload']  = "user.php?action=index";

        } else {

            $res['server']  = "Error delete data!#".$sql1;

        }

        echo json_encode($res);

    } elseif (isset ($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'checkreg') {

        $sql1       = "SELECT count(finger_id) as ct FROM demo_finger WHERE user_id=".$_GET['user_id'];
        $result1    = mysql_query($sql1);
        $data1      = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

        if (intval($data1['ct']) > intval($_GET['current'])) {
            $res['result'] = true;          
            $res['current'] = intval($data1['ct']);         
        }
        else
        {
            $res['result'] = false;
        }
        echo json_encode($res);

    } else {

        echo "Parameter invalid..";

    }
?>
```

Comment: Maybe! But only if you show us the PHP code that you use to update the database

Comment: Is this code in a `.php` file or a `.html` file

Comment: show your javascript code and also php code

Comment: @RiggsFolly its a php file

Comment: @AshokDevatwal my javascript code

<script type="text/javascript">

   $('title').html('Add user');

   function user_store() {

    user_name = $('#user_name').val();

    push('user.php?action=store&user_name='+user_name);

   }

Comment: NO... edit your question and add all the requested information in there

Comment: @RiggsFolly my code when submit to database 

if (count($res) > 1) {

   echo json_encode($res);

  } else {

   $sql  = "INSERT INTO demo_user SET user_name='".$_GET['user_name']."' ";
   $sql1  = "INSERT INTO demo_macaddress SET macaddress='".$_POST['mac_address']."' ";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $result = mysql_query($sql1);
   
   if ($result) {

    $res['result'] = true;
    $res['reload']  = "user.php?action=index";

   } else {

    $res['server'] = "Error insert data!";

   }

   echo json_encode($res);

  }

Comment: oh im sorry..im new to this website

Comment: @RiggsFolly i already add link to my code..im sory my code have 296 lines

Comment: this error due to your store action not return a proper json formated responce  , value of $res is not encoded proprely in json format . what is return checkUserName() function ?